# d3.js rectangle feature plotted as arc in Mollweide projection

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geospatial

I am trying to plot a rectangle using d3.js under the Mollweide projection. However, when I run the following script the rectangle appears as an arc or curved rectangle. I find the bahaviour somewhat strange since the parallels in Mollweide projection are just straight lines. Could someone explain the effect? The same effect persists in other latitudes and other projections (even the Equirectangular one) as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-geo-projection.v1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var mainSVG = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width', 500).attr('height', 500);

var projection = d3.geoMollweide().scale(400).translate([250,750])
var path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

d3.json('test.json', function(error, vData) {

    var features = vData.features;

    mainSVG.selectAll('path')
        .data(features)
      .enter().append('path')
        .attr('d', path)
        .style('fill', 'red')
        .style('stroke', 'black');

})
</script>
```

the geojson file:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "DN": 0 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 7.6, 65.0 ], [ 60.4, 65.0 ], [ 60.4, 63.4 ], [ 7.6, 63.4 ], [ 7.6, 65.0 ] ] ] } }
]
}
```

**and the resulting figure**:

[image]

**An even more weird result when I try to plot several neighbouring rectangles at different latitudes**:
[image]

Comment: Cross-posted as https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/254184/115

Answer (score 3, accepted):

D3 paths follow great arcs, the shortest distance between two points. These two points are in three dimensional space on an ellipsoid, so the shortest path between them may not correspond to the shortest path between them measured in a projected 2 dimensional space.

Taking an extreme example, imagine a point at 85°N, 90°W, another at 85° N, 90 °E. Despite being on the same parallel, the shortest distance between the two is a short jaunt over the north pole. D3 would draw this line as two vertical lines to the top of the map (on a stereotypical equirectangular map: equator in the middle, north at the top) rather than a horizontal line along the 85th parallel.

If you wish to have visibly straight lines between two points on a projected plane, project the vertices onto the projected plane (svg coordinate space), and draw a line connecting these projected points. This could be done by creating a new geojson where every lat,long pair of the original geojson has been projected (`projection([x,y])`) and then drawn with a null projection: `.attr(d, d3.geoPath(null))`

Comment: Good answer! Also, dividing the coordinates into small segments will work for OP's code. For instance, instead going from 7W to 60W, going from 7 to 10, from 10 to 20, from 20 to 30 etc... until 60 will generate a straight line. The more arrays the more *"straight"* the line.

Comment: Great answer! I had both suggested solutions in mind but I just couldn't figure out the reason for bending the lines