# point in polygon using leaflet-pip and d3.geoContains

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geojson

I am perplexed as to what I am doing wrong here. I have a geoJson object and I am trying to find which feature contains a given point. 
When I am using `d3.geoContains` I got back the false results, ie those polygons that **do not** contain the point.

What I do for now is to use `point in polygon` from https://mapbox.github.io/leaflet-pip/ which seems to work fine, however I dont know what I am missing with `d3.geoContains`. According to the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo#geoContains) it should return true if the object contains the point.

Attached is a simple case where I have 4 squares, two at the bottom row, one next to the other, and the other two at the top row. I am testing to find the polygon containing point [0.7, 0.7] and `pip` returns the correct answer, top-right, but `d3.geoContains` returns the other three squares.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <!--d3 -->
    <script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js'></script>

    <!-- leaflet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css"/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet-src.js"></script>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-pip@1.1.0/leaflet-pip.js"></script>

</head>
<body>


<script>
    var my_squares = {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {"id": "bottom_left"},
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Polygon",
                    "coordinates": [[[0.0, 0.0], [0.5, 0.0], [0.5, 0.5], [0.0, 0.5], [0.0, 0.0]]],
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties":  {"id": "bottom_right"},
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Polygon",
                    "coordinates": [[[0.5, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 0.0]]],
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {"id": "top_right"},
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Polygon",
                    "coordinates": [[[0.5, 0.5], [1.0, 0.5], [1.0, 1.0], [0.5, 1.0], [0.5, 0.5]]],
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {"id": "top_left"},
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Polygon",
                    "coordinates": [[[0.0, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 0.5]]],
                }
            },
        ]
    }

    var my_point = [0.7, 0.7];
    console.log('Point is: ' + my_point)
    var geo_out = my_squares.features.filter(function(d) {return d3.geoContains(d, my_point)});
    console.log('From d3.geoContains');
    geo_out.forEach(function(d){console.log(d.properties.id)});

    console.log('')

    var polygons = L.geoJson(my_squares, {});
    var res = leafletPip.pointInLayer(my_point, polygons)[0].feature.properties.id;
    console.log('From pip');
    console.log(res)

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your coordinates are in counterclockwise order.

Because the [original GeoJSON 1.0 spec](https://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html) had nothing to say on winding order, so d3-geo [made up its own rule](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/blob/1209cc88975b8b6cd443ae787317f65896c7e3dd/README.md):

> Spherical polygons also require a winding order convention to determine which side of the polygon is the inside: the exterior ring for polygons smaller than a hemisphere must be clockwise, while the exterior ring for polygons larger than a hemisphere must be anticlockwise.

Therefore, in d3-geo's view, your polygons are holes; the features cover everything everywhere except in those holes. [Here's a visual example of what's happening](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/a7bdfeb041e850799a8d3dce4d8c50c8).

---

Unfortunately, the [GeoJSON spec in RFC7946](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-3.1.6) later did specify this, and specified *exactly the opposite*:

> A linear ring MUST follow the right-hand rule with respect to the
> area it bounds, i.e., exterior rings are counterclockwise, and
> holes are clockwise.

According to [a quick reading of its test suite](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-pip/blob/429275c73c9968a305ab059820cb1be2a3acc281/test/leaflet-pip.js#L70-L75), it appears leaflet-pip assumes this winding order, so it understands your polygons.

---

If we put your rings in clockwise order, the answers are both `top_right`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <!--d3 -->
    <script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js'></script>

    <!-- leaflet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css"/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet-src.js"></script>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-pip@1.1.0/leaflet-pip.js"></script>

</head>
<body>


<script>
    var my_squares = {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {"id": "bottom_left"},
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Polygon",
                    "coordinates": [[[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]],
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties":  {"id": "bottom_right"},
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Polygon",
                    "coordinates": [[[0.5, 0.0], [0.5, 0.5], [1.0, 0.5], [1.0, 0.0], [0.5, 0.0]]],
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {"id": "top_right"},
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Polygon",
                    "coordinates": [[[0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5]]],
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {"id": "top_left"},
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Polygon",
                    "coordinates": [[[0.0, 0.5], [0.0, 1.0], [0.5, 1.0], [0.5, 0.5], [0.0, 0.5]]],
                }
            },
        ]
    }

    var my_point = [0.7, 0.7];
    console.log('Point is: ' + my_point)
    var geo_out = my_squares.features.filter(function(d) {return d3.geoContains(d, my_point)});
    console.log('From d3.geoContains');
    geo_out.forEach(function(d){console.log(d.properties.id)});

    console.log('')

    var polygons = L.geoJson(my_squares, {});
    var res = leafletPip.pointInLayer(my_point, polygons)[0].feature.properties.id;
    console.log('From pip');
    console.log(res)

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

(I was surprised that pip's answer didn't reverse.  Perhaps it just assumed you meant an exterior ring anyway, or maybe it doesn't support polygons with holes in the first place.)

Comment: Both great answers! Many thanks Anko and Andrew, it didnt cross my mind it had to do with d3-geo view of the winding order as I was pretty much sure the standard was that counterclockwise is for holes

Comment: Oops! typo in my comment above, at the very end. I meant to say that "....counterclockwise is not for holes"

Answer (score 1):

D3, including d3.geoContains, uses spherical geometry. This is in contrast to almost every other web mapping tool which treat latitude longitude points as Cartesian.

This means every connection between two points in a geographical feature follows great circle distance (which is why it is harder to draw bounding boxes, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46028587/7106086), while other libraries may make it harder to draw great circle arcs, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47053595/7106086)).

By using spherical geometry, the antimeridian doesn't cause as many problems, but conversely, winding order matters: are you drawing everywhere *except* an area of interest or the area of interest itself.

This applies to d3.geoContains:
Your polygons are wound in the opposite order as they are supposed to be. Instead of bounding a small box, they bound the rest of the world - which is why you get the opposite outcome as expected.

You have two options: rewind the polygons , for example with [turf.js](https://turfjs.org/docs/#rewind):

```
var fixed = features.map(function(feature) {
    return turf.rewind(feature,{reverse:true});
})
```

Or, if all your polygons are consistently wound in reverse, you could just invert the outcome of d3-geoContains, though this seems like a much less ideal solution.